# Unable to make deb file of Qt 5.4 app in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt5, ubuntu-14.04, deb

I am able to make deb file of Qt 5.2.1 app in Ubuntu 14.04 but unable to make deb file of Qt 5.4 app in Ubuntu 14.04 and got below errors.

```
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5: undefined reference to `QPdfEnginePrivate::paperRect() const'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5: undefined reference to `QPdfEnginePrivate::pageRect() const'

//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5: undefined reference to `QFontEngine::glyphCache(void const*, QFontEngineGlyphCache::Type, QTransform const&) const'
```

I am just guessing that .so files present at the path usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ are compatible with Qt 5.2.1 but not with Qt5.4.

There is no change in .so files at the path path usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ if we install or uninstall Qt 5.2.1 or Qt 5.4.

If anyone has idea, then please let me know so that I can resolve my issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download QT from www.qt.io/download-open-source/ .
And install Qt 5.4 with 'sudo', then it will install under /opt/Qt .

After install, set your env ( .bashrc or else) with bellow script.
(My system is x64 so please check the QT_BASE_DIR for your system.)

```
QT_BASE_DIR=/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64
export QTDIR=$QT_BASE_DIR
export PATH=$QT_BASE_DIR/bin:$PATH

if [[ $(uname -m) == "x86_64" ]]; then
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$QT_BASE_DIR/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$QT_BASE_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$QT_BASE_DIR/lib/i386-linux-gnu:$QT_BASE_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$QT_BASE_DIR/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Comment: madenmud, Thanks for your answer. I have tried with the way as you suggested but still getting the same issue. Somewhere I read that I need to create deb on Ubuntu 15.04. Ubuntu 14.04 supported QT 5.2 .so files and Ubuntu 15.04 compatible with QT 5.4 .so files.